# Use config value from xml in template

Tags: database, template, configuration, xml

I'm working on a magento project that's created by another firm. In a template file (`app/design/frontend/companytheme/default/template/catalog/product/featured.phtml`) they have:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;'.$storeId,
    'dbusername',
    'dbpassword',
    array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND    =>  "SET NAMES utf8",
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE               =>  PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING,
        PDO::ATTR_CASE                  =>  PDO::CASE_LOWER
        )
    );
```

But when I push this to my staging environment the database settings aren't equal. How can I create a **config xml** in app/etc and use these database settings in the specific template?

Answer (score 1):

Create the database connection in /app/etc/local.xml :

**Default_setup :**

```
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Tue, 13 Oct 2015 13:00:15 +0000]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[a70ec048c7a4263e75f4855e010862e0]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[user]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[password]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[dbname]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

**Add another node here to handle the new database connection**

```
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Tue, 13 Oct 2015 13:00:15 +0000]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[a70ec048c7a4263e75f4855e010862e0]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[user]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[password]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[dbname]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>

        <second_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[user]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[password]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[dbname]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </second_setup>

        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

**Connection new database like:**

```
$config = Mage::getConfig()->getResourceConnectionConfig('second_setup');
        $dbConfig = array(
        'host'      => $config->host,
        'username'  => $config->username,
        'password'  => $config->password,
        'dbname'    => $config->dbname
    );

$connection = Zend_Db::factory('Firebird', $dbConfig);
```

**Use Queries like:**

```
$connection->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM table");
$connection->update('table',array('field'=>'value'),$where);
```